# Epoch time and local time, different time zone

Tags: r, date

I want to convert epoch time to the local time. As you can see here, I have different time zones and I want to get a local time for each row. How can I do the conversion considering each time zone?

```
 df <- data.frame(Epoch_Time = c(1460230930,1460231830, 1459929664),
              Time_Zone = c("UTC−12:00", "UTC+10:00", "UTC-9:00"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your epoch time as POSIX and then you can manipulate more easily.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  time_epoch = as.POSIXct(
    c(1460230930,1460231830, 1459929664), tz = "UTC", origin = "1970-01-01"
  ),
  time_zone = c("UTC-12:00", "UTC+10:00", "UTC-09:00")
)

df <- mutate(df,
             time_zone = as.numeric(substr(time_zone, 4, 6)),
             time_local = as.character(time_epoch + hours(time_zone))
      )

df

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#            time_epoch time_zone          time_local
#                <dttm>     <dbl>               <chr>
# 1 2016-04-09 21:42:10       -12 2016-04-09 11:42:10
# 2 2016-04-09 21:57:10        10 2016-04-10 09:57:10
# 3 2016-04-06 10:01:04        -9 2016-04-06 03:01:04
```

Notes:

1. I haven't put the effort in to properly generalise the conversion
   from your UTC strings, only enough to use for this example. Ideally,
   you want *Olson Names* instead of offsets, you can get these
   [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
2. the `time_local` is stored as character, you cannot store a date/time column with multiple time zones, they are stored with a
   single value, see `attributes(df$time_epoch)`

   ```
   attributes(df$time_epoch)
   # $class
   # [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
   #
   # $tzone
   # [1] "UTC"
   ```